# Making cell result permanent in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet which downloads live stock data daily ( if today() etc.) and applies this to a portfolio and values it. I need to transfer that value to another cell and it be a permanent record of the day's value and not be overwritten. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use a script to get the value and write it into another cell. To append all values in a range into a new row in another tab, use `Array.flat()` and `Sheet.appendRow()`. See the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script for sample code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)